# What is the % in the Leaks Instrument - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

Im pretty new to the leaks instrument and was wondering when I am selecting my code that it says are leaks each one has a % next to them, some are 66.66% others are 33.33% and some are 100%

Can anyone give some advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that "100% of the leaked memory is in this part of the tree" or "33.3% of the leaked memory is in this part of the tree." As you go further down it will get smaller depending on how much of the leaked memory is in each branch of the tree.